# How to solve listview issue in flutter

Tags: flutter

I created a page with flutter but It shows me an error that is about height of listview.
I know other persons answer this question in other topics but those solutions didn't work for me.
I tried Container widget, Flexible widget, Expanded Widget and etc but nothing works for me
This is my code:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Widget myContainer() {
    return Container(
      width: 5,
      height: 5,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("assets/images/dance.jpg"))),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            "Dance",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Color(0xFF1b0a29),
                fontSize: 16),
          ),
          Text(
            "Season",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Color(0xFF1b0a29),
                fontSize: 16),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "4.5",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        fontSize: 10,
                        color: Color(0xFF1b0a29)),
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.star,
                    color: Color(0xFF1b0a29),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.purple),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 120,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xFF1b0a29),
                      borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(90.0))),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.9,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(90.0))),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4.5,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(90.0)),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.grey[400],
                                      spreadRadius: 1.0,
                                      blurRadius: 1,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 3))
                                ],
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 30.0, right: 10.0, left: 10.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(
                                          Icons.arrow_back,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                        Icon(
                                          Icons.search,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 100,
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          "Updates",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 40),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 15, left: 8, right: 8),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: 70,
                                      height: 70,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                          image: DecorationImage(
                                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                              image: AssetImage(
                                                  "assets/images/photo.jpg"))),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        "Hooman Hooshyar",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 14),
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          "25 June",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 11,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 100,
                                  ),
                                  Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down)
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Row(children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0, top: 10),
                                child: Container(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "This is a wonderful test for UI Design with flutter.\n"
                                    "This is just a test",
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ]),
                            Directionality(
                              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                              child: Expanded(
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              right: 20.0),
                                          child: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                                        ),
                                        Text("428"),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              right: 20.0),
                                          child:
                                              Icon(Icons.comment_bank_outlined),
                                        ),
                                        Text("123")
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: 5,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return myContainer();
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is Error:

```
Exception caught by rendering library
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 1862 pos 16: 'constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:250:32
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderShrinkWrappingViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1862:16)
#3      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
#4      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#5      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
#6      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#6d80e relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: MISSING
...  axisDirection: right
...  crossAxisDirection: down
...  offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#bfde7(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#f5661, ScrollDirection.idle)
RenderObject: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#6d80e relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: MISSING
  axisDirection: right
  crossAxisDirection: down
  offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#bfde7(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#f5661, ScrollDirection.idle)
...  child 0: RenderSliverPadding#6b771 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: layoutOffset=None
...    constraints: MISSING
...    geometry: null
...    padding: EdgeInsets.zero
...    textDirection: ltr
...    child: RenderSliverList#56e3b NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...      parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...      constraints: MISSING
...      geometry: null
...      no children current live
════════ Exception caught by rendering library
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#6d80e relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:250:32

════════ Exception caught by rendering library
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#c97ed relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:250:32

════════ Exception caught by rendering library
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#67a33 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:250:32


════════ Exception caught by rendering library
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#61d91 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:250:32

════════ Exception caught by rendering library
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#055f4 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:250:32
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#14d79 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:250:32
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#d6646 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:250:32
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#34ee4 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:250:32
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#86282 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:250:32
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#316d9 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:91:26
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#bb5a7 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Container file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:84:17
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderDecoratedBox#47cc8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Container file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:84:17
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#b921b relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:82:20
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#07c8b NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Container file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:78:11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderDecoratedBox#4031c NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Container file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:78:11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#706d1 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:76:13
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#0c70d relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:75:12
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Null check operator used on a null value
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:76:13
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 1862 pos 16: 'constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:250:32
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderShrinkWrappingViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1862:16)
#3      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
#4      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
#5      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
#6      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#6d80e relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: MISSING
...  axisDirection: right
...  crossAxisDirection: down
...  offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#bfde7(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#f5661, ScrollDirection.idle)
RenderObject: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#6d80e relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: MISSING
  axisDirection: right
  crossAxisDirection: down
  offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#bfde7(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#f5661, ScrollDirection.idle)
...  child 0: RenderSliverPadding#6b771 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: layoutOffset=None
...    constraints: MISSING
...    geometry: null
...    padding: EdgeInsets.zero
...    textDirection: ltr
...    child: RenderSliverList#56e3b NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...      constraints: MISSING
...      geometry: null
...      no children current live
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#6d80e relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:250:32
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#c97ed relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:250:32
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#67a33 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1919 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///D:/Android/Project/Flutter/Tutorials/This_will_remove/reminde_project/lib/main.dart:250:32
```

Comment: did you tried using expanded widget in listView ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It bursts because you raised the column inside. expanded and MyContainer explodes because you give a fixed height and height. You also need to remove fontsize sizes in MyContainer. explodes because of them.
follow the first steps;
wrap the builder with expanded,
then remove MyContainer height and width and fontsize. It will be alright.

```
Widget myContainer() {
  return Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  ),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Text(
        "Dance",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Color(0xFF1b0a29),
        ),
      ),
      Text(
        "Season",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Color(0xFF1b0a29),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Text(
                "4.5",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    fontSize: 10,
                    color: Color(0xFF1b0a29)),
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.star,
                color: Color(0xFF1b0a29),
              )
            ],
           ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

---

```
           Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: 5,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return myContainer();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: I also removed those lines because I did not have a photo. Try it without png if it bursts with a photo then wrap the photo in expanded. also if you want listviewbuilder to give a fixed size. You need to give both listviewBuilder a fixed height and MyContainer, but this is not a healthy situation. I recommend you to make the previous fixed dimensions flexible. This is because it tries to prevent screen burst on different phones.

Answer (score 1):

in your myContainer() Column, add the mainAxisSize property:

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min
```

Wrap your listview in a container with a defined height:

```
Container(
 height: 300,
 child: Listview.builder(
```

Comment: That's not work. I think listview has problem

Comment: add this in your listview.builder: 

physics: ClampingScrollPhysics()

Comment: I changed my listview. This is my listview: ListView.builder(
                        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: 5,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return myContainer();
                        }, . But it's not work too

Comment: I just noticed you have several Columns, try adding mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min to all of them

Edit: spelling

Comment: I added "mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min" to all column widgets but it didn't fix

Comment: wrap your listview in a container with a defined height. That should solve it

Comment: I did that before. I putted listview inside container and set height for that but that didn't work too!!!

Comment: It worked, I just tried it. Add in all the mainAxisSize property in all columns then add the height. That would solve it.

Comment: I changed my listview like this: Container(
                        height: 5,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: 5,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return myContainer();
                          },
                        ),
                      ), and all columns have mainAxisSize, but it doesn't work!!!